# Laravel login redirect to user's page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

### The goal

After login, I want users to be redirected to their personal page, e.g. `/authors/1`

### First attempts

The default login redirect url can be adjusted in `LoginController.php` by:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/'
```

My first try was simply to say:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/authors/'.Auth::id();
```

However, this is not allowed (`Constant expression contains invalid operations`)

What is the right way to redirect to e.g. `/authors/1`? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Set `$redirectTo` inside constructor instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5.4 you can override `authenticated()` method in the `LoginController.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect('authors/'.$user->id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Implementing this gives the following error though: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request`

Comment: The correct addition to make the answer work was `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` Thanks.